# App prints "[[ljava.lang.string;@40585b18" rather than array value

Tags: java, android

I have this printed "[[ljava.lang.string;@40585b18" instead of a vlaue from the string array called answers.

At the moment i am not picky really as to what is pritned out. Just get the app to display something meaningfull from the array will be a good place to start right now.

The following two lines of code is what currently prints:

TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);

quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers) ;

```
package ks3.mathsapp.project;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MathsMultiplicationActivity extends Activity {

TextView quesnum;
TextView ques;
TextView ans1;
TextView ans2;
TextView ans3;
TextView ans4;


int qno = 0;
int right_answers = 0;
int wrong_answers = 0;
int rnd1;
int rnd2;

String [] questions = {"How much mph does the F-Duct add to the car?",
          "What car part is considered the biggest performance variable?",
          "What car part is designed to speed up air flow at the car rear?",
          "In seconds, how long does it take for a F1 car to stop when travelling at 300km/h?",
          "How many litres of air does an F1 car consume per second?",
          "What car part can heavily influence oversteer and understeer?",
          "A third of the cars downforce can come from what?",
          "Around how much race fuel would be consumed per 100km?","The first high nose cone was introduced when?",
          "An increase in what, has led to the length of exhaust pipes being shortened drastically?"};

String [] [] answers = {{"3","5","8","9"},
{"Tyres","Front Wing","F-Duct","Engine"},
{"Diffuser","Suspension","Tyres","Exhaust"},
{"4","6","8","10"},
{"650","10","75","450"},
{"Suspension","Tyres","Cockpit","Chassis"},
{"Rear Wing","Nose Cone","Chassis","Engine"},
{"75 Litres","100 Litres","50 Litres","25 Litres"},
{"1990","1989","1993","1992"},
{"Engine RPM","Nose Cone Lengths","Tyre Size","Number of Races"}};

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.multiplechoice);

// Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
quesnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNum);
ques = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
ans1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
ans2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
ans3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
ans4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers) ;            
TextView quesAns2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2); 
quesAns2.setText("2) " + answers) ;   
TextView quesAns3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
quesAns3.setText("3) " + answers) ;   
TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers) ;   
}                    
}
```

Comment: try indexing your array.. e,g, `answers[0]` for assigning the value of `quesAns1`. Also, stuff like that belongs in your resources, not hardcoded into the app.

Comment: How would i go about storing an array of the answers in the resources?

Comment: 'App prints “ljava.lang.string;@40585b18”'. Actually it didn't: it printed “[[Ljava.lang.String;@40585b18”. Please be accurate when posting error messages, stack traces, unexpected outputs etc.

Answer (score 2):

you are doing it wrong. It should be something like:

```
quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[0][0]);  //change index values as required
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback

TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
        quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[2][1]) ;            
    
I added to similar to what you said. i can read from the array now. model. How would i go about matching each question up with teh correct asnwers?

i have been using a flash quiz i used last year as the model for code which can be found:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/17215213/Build-a-Quiz-in-AS3

However translating actionscript to java is proving difficult.

Comment: I would suggest you to use some sort of `HashMap<String, String>` to pair questions and answers...

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the text to `"1) " + answers`, and `answers` is an array of arrays of Strings.
Instead you should get the String from the array: `answers[0][0]` would get the first answer to the first question for example.